# how app fall in Infinite loop routing with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, loops, routes

I have a small issue. Angular app falls in infinite loop if user has a network delay. User do make navigation from my other app. Main app looking for authToken query params from redirect url then should show  dashboard. Belowe code snipped from app.component.ts file.

```
if (params.get('authToken')) {
            this._session.setAuthToken(params.get('authToken'));
            this._store.dispatch(availableActions.getAclActions());
        }

if (this._session.getAuthToken()) {
            this._router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        }
```

Routing in my app.module.ts look like

```
const mainRoutes = [
    { path: 'auth', loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule' },
    { path: '', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule' }
];
```

Routing in my home.module.ts

```
const moduleRoutes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
        data: { breadcrumb: { label: 'Start', link: '/' } },
        children: [
            { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: '../dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
            { path: 'communication', loadChildren: '../communication/communication.module#CommunicationModule', canActivate: [HasSessionGuard] },
            { path: 'archive', loadChildren: '../database-archive/database-archive.module#DatabaseArchiveModule', canActivate: [HasSessionGuard] },
            { path: 'configuration', loadChildren: '../configuration/configuration.module#ConfigurationModule', canActivate: [HasSessionGuard] },
            { path: 'system', loadChildren: '../system/system.module#SystemModule', canActivate: [HasSessionGuard] },
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
        ]
    }
];
```

I must added if app is run without query authToken user can makes log in and app redirect to dashboart correct.

[Routing tracking if app fall in loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nK0B3.png)

Comment: I resolve my issue. Action availableActions.getAclActions() in own effect make redirect in dashboard.